# How to list SQL 2005 Express instances

Tags: c++, instance, sql-server-2005-express, sqldmo

I would like to list what instances of SQL 2005 Server (Express Editon) are installed on local or remote machine (my app is in Native C++). I found that i can make it by SQLDMO, however it seems that SQLDMO does not see SQL 2005 Express Edition and call to ListAvailableSqlServers returns empty list.

How can i make it? Playing with system registry is an extreme solution and applies only for local machines.

Answer (score 1):

Got it... Found SQLBrowseConnect. Answer is as usual in MSDN :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SqlDataSourceEnumerator.GetDataSources()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources.aspx). Works well in C# and VB.Net though I haven't tried it from C++.

Comment: Thanks. I checked that method but it is available since .NET 2.0 and this version of framework is unreachable to me. I work with VS2003.