# List SQL Express 2005 instances using VB6 code

Tags: sql-server-2005, vb6, instances

How to list all the instances of SQL Server 2005 Express Edition using vb6 application?

Answer (score 1):

This will list all SQL Server instances using SQL-DMO. You will need to filter for Express instances.

```
Function listServers(vControl As Object)
    Dim oApp As SQLDMO.Application 
    Dim oNames  As SQLDMO.NameList 

    Set oApp = New SQLDMO.Application 
    Set oNames = oApp.ListAvailableSQLServers() 

    For Each oName In oNames 
        vControl.AddItem oName 
    Next 
End Function
```

From [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/introductiontosql-dmo/463/).

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825687/how-to-list-sql-2005-express-instances) says that it won't find Express instances; need to use `SQLBrowseConnect`.

Answer (score 1):

[This sample](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=40805&lngWId=1) is using `SQLBrowseConnect` API.